# Magento migration breaking - sub-pages return 404

Tags: php, mysql, .htaccess, magento, magento-1.7

Recently got a request from a client to migrate their magento site from one host to another. They just recently upgraded to magento 1.7. I managed to flesh out all the db issues and reset the necessary indexes to 0, so the homepage now displays properly and I have access to the admin.

However, I've run into the troubling issue that all the sub-pages on the migrated site are returning 404s. For reference:

Live site:

```
http://seacadetshipsstore.com/magento/uniform-items.html
```

Migrated site:

```
http://173.239.43.221/~seacadet/magento/uniform-items.html
```

Has anyone run into something like this before? The other difference in the two environments is that the live site admin is at /magento/admin/, but the migrated site is at /magento/index.php/admin/.....so I'm wondering if it's perhaps a .htaccess issue? This is all relatively new to me, so forgive me if it's moronically simple - just didn't want to waste time beating a rock against it when I can give karma to an expert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically you need to check your host settings

http:// 173. 239 .43. 221/~seacadet/magento/index.php/uniform-items.html

this link works perfect. no htaccess issue. just need to on server rewrite module on host.

Comment: if your magento is not in the root dir, you have to set a RewriteBase.

Comment: Thanks! RewriteBase was set but I hadn't included the extra ~seacadet that was on the migrated server. I knew it was going to be embarrasingly simple.